# How do I install GDAL on Centos 6?

Tags: python, django, centos6, gdal

I'm trying to install GeoDjango, it looks like I need PostGis. I got PostGis install fine on my mac, but I can't get it install on Centos 6.

Following this here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211962/yum-install-postgis-on-centos-7

I get stuck on:

```
yum install gdal-devel.x86_64
```

Here's what I get for errors

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: gpsbabel-1.5.0-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libQtCore.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
           Requires: libpoppler.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
           Requires: libpoppler.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-java-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
           Requires: libpoppler.so.5()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```